# JPQL query: Item that belongs to multiple categories

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, jpql

Having an entity **Items** that have a collection field called **categories**, I need to find items that belong at least to two specific categories, but I cant find the way to build the correct JPQL query.

```
@Entity
public class Items {
@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Category> categories;
}
```

I can find an item that have one category:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE :cat MEMBER OF item.categories
```

I can select items with any of several categories:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE :cat1 MEMBER OF item.categories OR :cat MEMBER OF item.categories
```

But when I try to select for items that have at least two specific categories, the following query gets no items:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE :cat1 MEMBER OF item.categories AND :cat2 MEMBER OF item.categories
```

Which is the correct way to do that?

Best regards,
Pablo.

Comment: Do you have entity with Items to Category relations?

Comment: I mean ItemsCategories entity

Comment: Yes, the Category entity has a ManyToMany relationship with Item entity:
@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER) private List<Category> categories;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem happened to me with ObjectDB.
I have contacted them too, and this was the answer:

> This seems to be the result of how JPQL queries are converted into SQL
>   like syntax before executing. MEMBER OF is implemented using JOIN with
>   a new synthetic variable for iteration over the collection. In your
>   query item.categories appears twice, but the same synthetic variable for
>   iterating over that collection is used for both occurrences, and that
>   variable cannot match both sides of the AND with the same value.
>
> Possibly we may have to use separate iteration per MEMBER OF as the
>   results as demonstrated by your post seem unacceptable (although JQPL
>   itself has strange behaviour in some known cases due to the conversion
>   to JOIN). However, using separate variables may sometimes make the
>   query more complex and slow unnecessarily (e.g. for the OR query in
>   your post), so any change requires careful planning.
>
> As a quick solution, you may replace AND of MEMBER OF with 2 explicit
>   JOIN variables for iteration over the collection with 2 independent
>   variables.

So, the solution is to use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item
FROM Item item JOIN item.categories cat1 JOIN item.categories cat2
WHERE cat1 = :cat1 AND cat2 = :cat2
```

I don't know if this a problem only for this specific JPA implementation (ObjectDB).
Anyway, if anybody has a similar problem, I hope that this post can help.